# jquery-ui, draggable item : does'nt work when position is absolute

Tags: html, jquery-ui, z-index, draggable, absolute

I'm trying to make draggable items contained in a position:absolute DIV.
It works well when dragged over a div declared earlier in the code, but this item will never appear over a [position:absolute] div declared later in the code, even when setting lower Z-index to this DIV...

Here's an example

```js
$(function(){
   $(".myClass").draggable({stack:".bg"});
  }(jQuery));
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div style="position:absolute;background-color:#3FF;width:200px;height:200px;border:1px solid #000;left:0px;top:0px;z-index:10;">
 <div class="myClass" style="position:absolute;left:10px;top:10px;width:70px;height:70px;background-color:#0F6;border:1px solid #000;z-index:100;">Draggable</div>
</div>
<div style="position:absolute;background-color:#FFC;width:200px;height:200px;border:1px solid #000;left:205px;top:0px;z-index:10;">
 <div class="myClass" style="position:absolute;left:10px;top:10px;width:70px;height:70px;background-color:#0F6;border:1px solid #000;z-index:100;">Draggable</div>
</div>
<div style="position:absolute;background-color:#9CF;width:200px;height:200px;border:1px solid #000;left:205px;top:205px;z-index:10;"></div>
```

Any idea of how i could solve that issue ?

Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your `z-index` on the parents elements. One easy way to resolve your problem is to simply remove them.
Or you can manipulate them on `start` and `stop` so the draggable parent is always at the top.
See here with manipulating on start and stop, but removing it from your HTML should also work.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".myClass").draggable({
    stack: ".myClass",
    start: function(e, ui) {
      ui.helper.parent().css('z-index', 30);
    },
    stop: function(e, ui){
      ui.helper.parent().css('z-index', 10);
      }
  });
}(jQuery));
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div style="position:absolute;background-color:#3FF;width:200px;height:200px;border:1px solid #000;left:0px;top:0px;z-index: 10;">
  <div class="myClass" style="position:absolute;left:10px;top:10px;width:70px;height:70px;background-color:#0F6;border:1px solid #000;z-index:100;">Draggable</div>
</div>
<div style="position:absolute;background-color:#FFC;width:200px;height:200px;border:1px solid #000;left:205px;top:0px;z-index: 10;">
  <div class="myClass" style="position:absolute;left:10px;top:10px;width:70px;height:70px;background-color:#0F6;border:1px solid #000;z-index:100;">Draggable</div>
</div>
<div style="position:absolute;background-color:#9CF;width:200px;height:200px;border:1px solid #000;left:205px;top:205px;z-indx: 10;"></div>
```